# Change selected option of <select> #2 based on selected option of <select> #1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

## What I have:

I have two select elements. `<select>` #1 is placed before a `<table>` whereas `<select>` #2 is placed beneath. The content and function of each element is identical with the exception of the class name.

## What I need:

1. Whenever an option is selected from `<select>` #1, I need the same option to be selected from `<select>` #2.
2. Vice versa.

## My code:

*Note: The following code does not demonstrate the vice versa.*

**HTML:**

```
<select class="togglebuildprojecturn_top togglebuildprojecturn">
    <option value="allbuildsprojects">All</option>
    <option value="prsm-spe-00058">prsm-spe-00058</option>
    <option value="buab-tes-00058">buab-tes-00058</option><option value="buab-exs-00058">buab-exs-00058</option>
    <option value="nonspecific">Build / Project non-specific</option>
</select>

<!--some table here-->

<select class="togglebuildprojecturn_bottom togglebuildprojecturn">
    <option value="allbuildsprojects">All</option>
    <option value="prsm-spe-00058">prsm-spe-00058</option><option value="buab-tes-00058">buab-tes-00058</option>
    <option value="buab-exs-00058">buab-exs-00058</option>                                              <option value="nonspecific">Build / Project non-specific</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.togglebuildprojecturn_top').on('change', function() {

    //First attempt that I expected to work...
    var selectedbuildprojecturn = $(this).val();
    var togglematch = ".togglebuildprojecturn_bottom[value='" + selectedbuildprojecturn +"']"
    alert(togglematch); //Just testing here (I know I should be using console logs :-)
    $(togglematch).attr('selected', true);

    //Testing for targeting without selector as variable...
    $(".togglebuildprojecturn_bottom[value='prsm-spe-00058']").attr('selected', true);

});

$('.togglebuildprojecturn_bottom').on('change', function() {

    //First attempt that I expected to work...
    var selectedbuildprojecturn = $(this).val();
    var togglematch = ".togglebuildprojecturn_top[value='" + selectedbuildprojecturn +"']"
    alert(togglematch); //Just testing here (I know I should be using console logs :-)
    $(togglematch).attr('selected', true);

});
```

**JSFiddle:**

For your convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/clarusdignus/rtY75/3/

## My question:

Why aren't the necessary options being selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can massively simplify your code by using the `class` you have on those elements and setting the `val()` on both to the currently selected value.

```
$('.togglebuildprojecturn').change(function() {
    $('.togglebuildprojecturn').val($(this).val());
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rtY75/4/)

Comment: Brilliance, concision and swiftness. Thanks. Selecting as correct answer after requisite time lapse.